# Must I used my developer account when downloading Xcode from the App Store?

Tags: xcode, app-store

Regular distributions of Xcode are now [available exclusively from the OS X App Store](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=02162012b), but (like many, I expect) my App Store account and developer accounts use different Apple IDs. All my previous installations of Xcode have used my developer account, and I also wonder if there are critical parts of the Xcode configuration (e.g. provisioning profiles, etc.) that rely on Xcode having been installed using the developer Apple ID.

Are there any undesirable consequences to simply installing Xcode from the App Store using my personal account? Or, should I (can I, must I) log in to the App Store using my developer Apple ID instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use whatever Apple ID you want to download Xcode from the Mac App Store. There's nothing special about what it downloads. You'll need to log in to the developer portal though to download beta versions.

Comment: Regarding the second part: If you get app store redemption codes for beta downloads (e.g. OS X beta) you can use your regular account in the App Store too. You just have to get the redemption codes from the developer portal. You can redeem them with your personal account. I think it's a good idea to avoid spreading app store downloads over several accounts.

Comment: Does the App Store download simply update my existing (non-App-Store) install; or does it do something different. I've had _terrible_ experiences with the process of "switching" from non-App-Store to App-Store installations with every other product I've tried (different install locations, changed features, loss of settings, duplicate files, etc.)

Comment: Your best bet is to uninstall the old version and then download the App Store version, I would say.

Comment: @mattjgalloway: That's what I'm absolutely trying to avoid, since there's quite a bit of configuration associated with the present installation. But that's really a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9672209/656912).

Answer (score 1):

You can download Xcode (and lots of other stuff) from [Apple's developer downloads website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

I very much doubt, therefore, that it matters whether you got it from the Mac App Store or not.

Comment: This may be the beginning of an answer to my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9672209/656912).