# Does the App Store version of Xcode cleanly replace the non-App-Store version?

Tags: xcode, app-store

Does the distribution of Xcode now [available from the OS X App Store](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=02162012b) replace a previous version [downloaded directly](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) from the Apple Developer site; or will "switching" from an Apple Developer installation to an App Store installation cause problems?

Comment: Like many, I've had _terrible_ experiences with the process of "switching" from non-App-Store to App-Store with other products (from  duplicate installations to loss of settings and data). Since I have a lot of configuration information associated with Xcode, I'm keen to avoid that experience here.

Comment: XCode 4.3.x can be placed side-by-side to 4.2.x (it offers you to delete previous version but it's not neccesary - tested).

Comment: @rokjarc: Will installing 4.3.x from the App Store migrate my settings from my Apple Developer 4.2.x installation?

Comment: i didn't have any special settings made for 4.2.1 so i can't really confirm or deny. But i don't have any problems using either version. The reason for keeping 4.2.1 is that there are many bug reports on 4.3

Comment: @rokjarc: Thanks. An earlier (now deleted) answer said that 4.3.x goes in `/Applications` rather than in `/Developer` (or is it just the App Store Version?). Can you confirm that?

Comment: true: 4.3.x goes in /Applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't have any problems switching from an installed 4.2 to a Mac App Store "installed" 4.3. All your profiles are stored in `~/Library`. All your certificates are in your keychain.

I've switched fully to 4.3 and not had a problem with any configuration. It's all still working just as it was in 4.2.

That said, if you do have *specific* problems, then please either open a new question for that specific problem or file a radar if it's something that Apple need to fix.

Comment: So far, this does indeed appear to work: I simply downloaded from the App Store (using my App Store Apple ID, which is [not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9669473/656912) as my developer Apple ID) and removed 4.2.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and no problems so far for me. Be sure to turn off wireless debugging though unless you want Xcode to crash every time you touch your device!